# How to empty retained value of email field on browser back on edge?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, microsoft-edge

I am using the following code to prevent value to be retained in the email field when I am pressing the back button on Edge browser.

```
<form>
    <input autocomplete="off" type="email" name="email" value="" id="Email123" placeholder="email" />
</form>

<form autocomplete="off">
    <input type="email" name="email" value="" id="Email123" placeholder="email" />
</form>
```

When I make use of `autocomplete="off"` in the form tag, it is of no use and the code does not work. Same is the case with `input` tag. The code is not working in either case.

How do I clear the email field when I click the back button on Edge browser?

Answer (score 0):

You could empty it in JS when the page loads.

```
document.getElementById('Email123').value = '';
```

this will only remove the autofilled text and not the default styles that go along with it on the input.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set autocomplete to a random invalid string value, like `autocomplete="nope"`

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion